# Force download not displaying size with gzip compression

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the below code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path);
```

The above code works fine, except it's not sending file size to browser.

I found that following thing in my htaccess is causing a problem. When I remove this part. My code is working as expected. If I add this line, Size is not displayed. So how can I disable this htaccess in particular folder only.

```
Options -Indexes
####################
# GZIP COMPRESSION #
####################
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to disable rewrite rules, then you can put a .htaccess file in the subfolder that contains `RewriteEngine On`, and the rules for the parent folder will be disabled (technically, replaced).

Similarly, if you want to disable authentication for a subfolder, you can create a .htaccess that contains `Satisfy Any`.

.htaccess rules cascade upwards, so Apache will look for a .htaccess file in the current folder and use the rules for it, then check the parent folder, etc.

Comment: I don't think this answer is relevant to the post.